# How to make types, classes, helper functions, etc. available in all components in Vue 3 with TypeScript without polluting the global scope?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

### Context

I'm building a Vue app (using the Composition API) in TypeSript and I'm running into an issue that I'm sure has been explained many times, but I just can't find a solution or even know how to best formulate the question. (In case that matters, I'm using Vite and VS Code.)

I have a TS file that contains **types, interfaces, enums, classes *and* functions** that are meant to be used globally.

Currently, in every single other `.vue` or `.ts` file, I have a lengthy import statement that imports everything I need from that file. As you can imagine, this is quite unwieldy.

Is there a way to make all the contents of that helper file usable everywhere, without having to import it?

### Things I've tried

1. Using Vue's [global properties](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties)

> This isn't recommended or documented for projects using the Composition API and `script setup`, which is what I'm doing. Besides, it doesn't work for enums, types or classes, as far as I could tell.

2. Using Vue's [provide/inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) or [composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) features

> This is equivalent to using `imports`, it just adds an extra step. Unless I'm missing something.

3. Importing the file in `main.ts`, then [augmenting the global scope](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) using `declare global {}` so that TS doesn't complain

> I don't know if this is a good practice (probably not) or if it even is supposed to work. I didn't manage to get it to behave. In particular, I didn't know how to get this to behave with classes, I kept getting `Declaration or statement expected` or `No implementation allowed in ambient contexts` errors.

4. Using option 3 for types only, and importing everything else

> That's what I ended up doing and it makes it sliiiightly more manageable as types is what I need a majority of the time, but I really wish I could find a way to do this for enums as well at the very least.

### To sum up...

**Is there a best practice for making all kinds of things from a single file available to an entire project without having to rely on import statements?**

---

Edit to clarify:

I know polluting the global object is bad. I'm not asking how to do that!
**I'm looking for solutions to *not* do that, while also not having to add 20 lines of imports to each file.**

I know it's doable:

- Rollup's [inject plugin](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/inject) automatically adds import statements everywhere needed based on a configuration file you create once
- [unplugin-auto-import](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-auto-import), as the name suggests, auto-imports APIs based on a list of presets

These two tools enable you to use the stuff you need everywhere without having to worry about making it available. (I actually use the latter, but didn't manage to get the former to work with Vite.) How can I do the same thing with helpers and utilities that exist in a file locally?

Comment: "Is there a best practice" - no.  Globals are evil. Modern IDEs support autoimports. That's the case for them. "I have a lengthy import statement that imports everything I need from that file" - you probably try to solve a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place because there should be no such file.

Answer (score 3):

If what you're looking for is an alternative to Vue2's `Vue.prototype`, here's [a useful resource](https://skirtles-code.github.io/vue-examples/patterns/global-properties.html#patching-third-party-libraries), authored by [@skirtle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8583563/skirtle). It covers all techniques you've already tried, and then some, outlining specific differences, pros and cons of each.

---

As a rule of thumb, the best practice in Composition API is ***not to have globals***.

The general concept of Composition API is to have granular control over the variables exposed to each `<template>` and not to expose anything other than what's actually being used in the current component/template.

In other words, wherever you need `stuff`, you have to `import` it:

```
import { useStuff } from './wherever'

const stuff = useStuff();
```

If you're inside a `<script setup>`, that should be enough.
If you're inside a `setup()`, inside a `defineComponent()`, you have to add `stuff` to the object returned by `setup()`, before you could use it in the `<template>`.

By definition, what `import` means is that ***it is not `global`***. You have to `import` it before you can use it.

---

Addendum: When our projects grow in complexity, the `import` section of each component inevitably grows and, as far as I can tell, this is the *"problem"* you're trying to solve.
Here's how I tackle it:

- I re-export all my stores from an `index.ts` file in the `src/store` folder and then I can import all stores needed in a component using a single import:
  `import { useAuth, useLayout, useSomethingElse } from '@/store';`
- I do the same thing with my types, using `@/types` folder
- Sometimes I also keep a `@/config` folder, as most of my apps are configuration driven

I'm not necessarily recommending the pattern, as I'm aware others might prefer different ones and I wouldn't want to start an argument over opinionated code architecture. What I can tell you is that my `import` sections throughout my projects no longer look messy.
Notably, when I <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + `click` a resource imported from a barrel import, my IDE takes me directly to the definition source, by-passing the re-export step.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is, like the article mentions, at the end of the day all of these solutions require you to manually "get" the thing you need, whether it's via `inject`, or a renderless component, or a Pinia store... so you might as well just use ES6 imports.

I don't want to have globals, I'm hoping for a solution that lets me "pretend" I have them but under the hood something else is happening. For instance, unless I'm mistaken, declaring a global type with TS doesn't actually do anything in terms of the JS output, it's just a build-time instruction. Right? I edited my OP to clarify.

Comment: One way to shorten imports is to make a `src/global` folder. Inside it, make an `index.ts` which imports and re-exports everything you want as globals. The only condition is that all exports are named. Now you can use `import { a, b, c } from '@/global'`. One line. Not 20.

Comment: Yeah, right now I have `import { a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k } from @/global` :)

Comment: Still better than importing them individually, with a different statement. That's all I'm saying. :)

Comment: I did just reorganize my stores with an index file after reading your comment, it doesn't necessarily solve my initial issue as I don't have that many stores but it future-proofed my dev process a bit, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vue [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html?redirect=true) - feel free to check the documentation!

Comment: As outlined in documentation, [mixins](https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#mixins) are no longer recommended in Vue3. In Vue3 Composition API is the *"preferred approach for code reuse between components"*.